# Postgres: regex and nested queries something like Unix pipes

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

**Command should do:** Give 1 as output if the pattern "*@he.com" is on the row excluding the headings:

```
 user_id | username |   email   |           passhash_md5           | logged_in | has_been_sent_a_moderator_message | was_last_checked_by_moderator_at_time | a_moderator 
---------+----------+-----------+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------------
       9 | he       | he@he.com | 6f96cfdfe5ccc627cadf24b41725caa4 |         0 |                                 1 | 2009-08-23 19:16:46.316272            |
```

In short, I want to connect many SELECT-commands with Regex, rather like Unix pipes. The output above is from a SELECT-command. A new SELECT-command with matching the pattern should give me 1.

[Related](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html)

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what you want to achieve? From the snippet you showed - I'm not sure what is it that you want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean

> `SELECT regexp_matches( (SELECT whatevername FROM users WHERE username='masi'), 'masi');`

you obviously can not feed the record (`*`) to `regexp_matches`, but I assume this is not what your problem is, since you mention the issue of nesting SQL queries in the subject.

Maybe you meant something like

> `SELECT regexp_matches( wn, 'masi' ) FROM (SELECT whatevername AS wn FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%masi%') AS sq;`

for the case when your subquery yields multiple results.

Comment: You are probably rigth. "ERROR:  subquery must return only one column" with the first command.

Comment: I suspect you've left your `*` there, because subquery `SELECT whatevername` may not return more than one column. Or what did you mean by "first command"?

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it with the command "SELECT regexp_matches( (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='he'), '*he.com');" to the table added to the question.

Comment: Read my query carefully. Not only I haven't written `SELECT *` there, but I also explicitly commented, saying that *you obviously can not feed the record (*) to regexp_matches*. You need to put the field name there, not asterisk (unless you only have one field).

Comment: Alias given to subselect. Subselects acts like a table in the FROM list, but obviously needs a name to be referred to (it is required for subqueries), no matter if you need to refer to it by name.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could use a regular expression query to match on the email address:

```
select * from table where email ~ '.*@he.com';
```

To return 1 from this query if there is a match:

```
select distinct 1 from table where email ~ '.*@he.com';
```

This will return a single row containing a column with 1 if there is a match, otherwise no rows at all. There are many other possible ways to construct such a query.

Comment: ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)

Comment: Why do I get the meta-data besides 1? Is it possible to filter it in Postgres?

Comment: you mean the column header? As far as I can tell you're using `psql` shell, perhaps what you're asking for is `psql -t` option (tuples only).

Comment: Right, the decoration around the data is just `psql` giving you a nice presentation. When you execute the query from a program, your program won't see the column headers or dividing lines.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your original query is:

```
select * from users where is_active = true;
```

And that you **really** want to match in any column (which is bad idea for a lot of reasons), and you want just to check if "*@he.com" matches any row (by the way - this is not correct regexp! correct would be .*@he.com, but since there are no anchors (^ or $) you can just write @he.com.

```
select 1 from (
    select * from users where is_active = true
) as x
where textin(record_out( x )) ~ '@he.com'
limit 1;
```

of course you can also select all columns:

```
select * from (
    select * from users where is_active = true
) as x
where textin(record_out( x )) ~ '@he.com'
limit 1;
```