# Confusion with shell-globbing wildcards and Regex

Tags: regex, wildcard

Initiated by the [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320721/postgres-regex-and-nested-queries-something-like-unix-pipes/1322144#1322144).

1. How can I use only Regex instead of wildcards?
2. Where do you really need wildcards and globbing if you can use Regex?
3. Have Regexes evolved from wildcards or vice versa?

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at with your "regex = language, wildcards = alphabets" metaphor. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Wildcards is a language too. But its semantics is not the same as the one of Regular Expressions. There are no quantifiers but just meta characters that behave similar to specific regular expressions (Wildcard–Regular Expression): `*` – `.+`, `?` – `.` and `[…]` – `[…]`.

Comment: Gumbo: Propositional logic does not contain quantifiers, the difference to predicate logic. Has the word "semantics" anything to do with them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your confusion is based on the differences between shell-globbing wildcards (the `*` character) and the regular expression symbol (the `*` character). Regexes *are not* shell-globbing, they are a lot more powerful and useful, but for everyday shell use, wildcards and shell-globbing are "good enough."

> 1. How can I use only Regex instead of wildcards?

Don't use the shell. Write a Perl/Python/Ruby/[your-choice-of-scripting-language-here] script to do the job for you. It'll probably be faster, since it won't have to fork so much.

> 2. Where do you really need wildcards and globbing if you can use Regex?

No. But in most shells, you *don't* have regexes, so you have globs. Think of them as a poor-man's regex.

> 3. Have Regexes evolved from wildcards or vice versa?

Regexes came from set theory, and specifically early text editors (one early Unix text editor called `ed` had a regex-like feature, which was then re-used in a little program called `grep`, which you might have heard of). I imagine wildcards have just been features of the shell. They can't be hard to implement, so shell writers would add them fairly quickly, and with little overhead.

Comment: History: I read from a BBC article that some neuroscientists invented Regex before formal mathematical formulation. I can look for it if someone wants.

Comment: Ps: It would be interesting to know more about the history of Wildcards. Regex is clear because it is just a CA.

Answer (score 5):

Described in the man page:

> -name pattern
>
> True if the last component of the pathname being examined matches pattern.  Special shell pattern matching characters (`[`, `]`, `*`, and `?`) may be used as part of pattern.  These characters may be matched explicitly by escaping them with a backslash (`\`).

So in other words, patterns that are usable in shell glob patterns are usable by `find`.

Man pages can generally tell you a lot. ;)

```
$ man find
```

for more information.

Comment: The shell matching system is called `glob`.

Answer (score 0):

My initial question had a wrong premise; they are wildcards, not regexes! Glob-program handles wildcards.

> Regular expressions
>
> Note  that
> wildcard patterns are not regular
> expressions, although they are a bit
> similar.  First of all, they match
> filenames, rather than text, and
> secondly, the conventions are not the
> same: for example, in a regular
> expression '*' means zero or more
> copies of the preceding thing.   Now
> that regular expressions have bracket
> expressions where the negation is
> indicated by a '^', POSIX has declared
> the effect of a  wildcard pattern
> "[^...]" to be undefined.

The explanation is not 100% thorough. For example, you can easily match filenames with Regex.

Comment: You can, but regexes tend to have a lot of overhead. I've found that, in general, sufficiently precise globs and the use of brackets is more than I need in the shell. If I need to do something more complicated that actually requires the use of regexes, it tends to be complicated enough to whip up a quick Perl script for rather than continuing to do through the shell.