# How to test if multiple files exist using a Bash script

Tags: bash

How can I use the `test` command for an arbitrary number of files, passed in using an argument with a wildcard?

For example:

```
test -f /var/log/apache2/access.log.* && echo "exists one or more files"
```

Currently, it prints

```
error: bash: test: too many arguments
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To avoid "too many arguments error", you need `xargs`. Unfortunately, `test -f` doesn't support multiple files. The following one-liner should work:

```
for i in /var/log/apache2/access.log.*; do test -f "$i" && echo "exists one or more files" && break; done
```

By the way, `/var/log/apache2/access.log.*` is called shell-globbing, not regexp. Please see [Confusion with shell-globbing wildcards and Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323805/confusion-with-shell-globbing-wildcards-and-regex) for more information.

Answer (score 56):

This solution seems to me more intuitive:

```
if [ `ls -1 /var/log/apache2/access.log.* 2>/dev/null | wc -l ` -gt 0 ];
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "ko"
fi
```

Comment: To me this was the most relevant answer to the question.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: good Idea but you can do it simpler:

ˋif ls -/var/log/apache2/access.log.* 2>/dev/null 1>&2ˋ works also, test [ ], backticks and wc -l  is not needed

Comment: For ones who don't know, you have to redirect `stderr` to a null file using `2>/dev/null` since if no match found, the error of `ls` wouldn't be printed out.

Answer (score 9):

First, store files in the directory as an array:

```
logfiles=(/var/log/apache2/access.log.*)
```

Then perform a test on the count of the array:

```
if [[ ${#logfiles[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
  echo 'At least one file found'
fi
```

Comment: Good idea. But when no file exists, the array content will be `['/var/log/apache2/access.log.*']` (one element containing the '*').
Suggestion: `[[ ${#logfiles[@]} -gt 1 || -e ${logfiles[0] ]]` or simply `[[ -e ${logfiles[0] ]]` (as dmaticzka does)

Comment: I would suggest adding `shopt -s nullglob` to avoid having an element in the array content if no file exists. In that case, the variable will be empty and the following test easier to make.

Comment: @simohe @skupjoe what about adding test for regular file? `if [[ ${#logfiles[@]} -gt 0 ]] && [[  -f ${#logfiles[@]} ]] ; then` . Sorry for being late for the party, so the `shopt -s nullglob` will not be necessary?

Comment: @zero0cool good catch! How could I miss that? :) And @sunta3iouxos good suggestion. The test should be: `if [[ ${#logfiles[@]} -gt 0 ]] && [[  -e ${logfiles[@]} ]]; then` to catch the condition for 0 files! Or use `-f` or `-d` to test for just files/directories ;).

Answer (score 6):

This one is suitable for use with the [Unofficial Bash Strict Mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/), no has non-zero exit status when no files are found.

The array `logfiles=(/var/log/apache2/access.log.*)` will always contain at least the unexpanded glob, so one can simply test for existence of the first element:

```
logfiles=(/var/log/apache2/access.log.*)

if [[ -f ${logfiles[0]} ]]
then 
  echo 'At least one file found'
else
  echo 'No file found'
fi
```

Comment: Great idea to test just [0] of array.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted a list of files to process as a batch, as opposed to doing a separate action for each file, you could use find, store the results in a variable, and then check if the variable was not empty.  For example, I use the following to compile all the .java files in a source directory.

```
SRC=`find src -name "*.java"`
if [ ! -z $SRC ]; then
    javac -classpath $CLASSPATH -d obj $SRC
    # stop if compilation fails
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then exit; fi
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to test if `ls` has something to list:

```
ls /var/log/apache2/access.log.* >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "exists one or more files"
```

Comment: Why is this one downvoted? Redirection is ugly? Better to use explicit if statement? Shouldn't use ls for scripting?

Answer (score 2):

Variation on a theme:

```
if ls /var/log/apache2/access.log.* >/dev/null 2>&1
then 
  echo 'At least one file found'
else
  echo 'No file found'
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -1 /var/log/apache2/access.log.* | grep . && echo "One or more files exist."
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using find

```
if [ $(find /var/log/apache2/ -type f -name "access.log.*" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "ok"
else
  echo "ko"
fi
```

Comment: I recommend to add `-maxdepth 1` before `-type f` to not go into subdirectories.

For speedup, use this: `find /var/log/apache2/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "access.log.*" -print -quit` (quit after first match)

Answer (score 1):

This condition below doesn't produce stderr. the condition's blackhole (/dev/null) doesn't prevent the stderr in cmd.

```
if [[ $(ls -1 /var/log/apache2/access.log.* | wc -l ) -gt 0 ]] 2> /dev/null
```

therefore I suggests this code.

```
if [[ $(ls -1 /var/log/apache2/access.log.* | wc -l ) -gt 0 ]] 2> /dev/null 
then
    echo "exists one or more files."
fi
```

Comment: it work also with broken symlinks?

Comment: If the symlink's target changed, you could also change the broken symlinks to connect the changed target. let's say link pair { target : symlink }. I change the target name with the suffix 1. So there is no target anymore but target1. your symlink is broken. but if you "ln -s -f target1 symlink" (-f is force write on existing symlink file option), your symlink will be alive.

Comment: Also, I changed the condition on the script above to a symlink, which works great.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

more simplyfied:

```
if ls /var/log/apache2/access.log.* 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
   echo "ok"
else
   echo "ko"
fi
```