# Test if a file exists

Tags: linux, bash

I struggle with the examples given if a file exists.
I want to check if multiple files exists in order to perform further operations.

```
ls -al:  
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 root   tomcat         6 Dec 16 11:25 documents_2019-12-12.tar.gz  

echo < [ -e ./documents_2019-12-12.tar.gz ]:  
    bash: [: No such file or directory
```

Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Edit:
I have a backup direcory with two files:

```
database_date.sql
documents_date.tar.gz
```

I need to check if both files for a given date are available. The directory shall contain these file-pairs for several dates.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what do you want to achieve with the wrong `echo` command. Do you mean something like `[ -e ./documents_2019-12-12.tar.gz ] && echo "file exists"`? You can combine multiple checks, e.g. `[ -e file1 ] && [ -e file2 ] && [ -e file3 ] && echo "all files exist"`

Comment: Also, you can test the existence on possibly multiple files use the following one liner: `for i in /my/path/files.*; do test -f "$i" && echo "exists one or more files" && break; done`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765569/test-if-multiple-files-exist) for explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a misunderstanding of where specific syntax is used. The `[ -e ./documents_2019-12-12.tar.gz ]` part of your command is syntax specific to the `if` clause in bash. Here's an example

```sh
if [ -e ./documents_2019-12-12.tar.gz ]
    then 
        echo "File Exists!"
fi
```

The square brackets [] are used to surround the check being performed by the if statement and the `-e` flag is specific to these `if` checks. More info here http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

To explain the error you're seeing, the `<` operator takes a file to the right and feeds the contents to the command on the left. In your case the `<` sees the `[` as the thing on the right so we try and read it as a file. Such a file doesn't exist so bash helpfully tells you that there's an error (the `bash: [: No such file or directory` bit) and then quits out.